# Hide Image For Responsive Layout

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to hide my image when the window size is less than 780. I tried methods from internet using media query but nothing seems to work out.

**Here is the style I tried**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  #content-desktop {display: none;}
  #content-mobile {display: block;}
  
}
```

**My html div of image**

```
<div className="d-flex justify-content-end mr-5 pr-2" id="content-desktop" style={{position:'relative'}}>
    <img id="content-desktop" src="/images/bars2.png" style={{
        backgroundPosition:'center',
        backgroundSize:'contain',
        aspectRatio:'0.9',
        display:'flex',
        flexGrow:'1',
        position:'relative',
        maxWidth:'23%',
        marginTop:"-23%"
    }} />
</div>
```

I want my image to hide when the screen is smaller than a desktop size.

Comment: move `#content-mobile {display: block;}` out of `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {` it should work

Comment: The div and the img have the same ID. You can't do that. They must be unique.

Comment: I removed ```#content-mobile {display: block;}``` from the stylesheet but still not working.

Comment: Yes I removed the id from my img tag.

Comment: Bootstrap has classes for this purpose - `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/`

Comment: move the "display:flex" from your style attribute, to an external css file, for example where you are defining the media queries.

Comment: Thankyou @Bagseye man, that was exactly what I needed.